# Centos Tmux - Bash script

Tags: java, bash, centos, sh, tmux

I have a java application (Minecraft server) which you start whit the following command.

`java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar spigot.jar`

I have 8 minecraft servers running on a dedicated server, so I use tmux.

I have a tmux session named "servers" and in that tmux session I have 8 windows.
Each window run a minecraft server.

When the servers restart they will start a script named start.sh

So my question is: How can I make the server start in the same session as it was in before?

Is it something like

`#!/bin/bash
tmux a -t servers #something java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar`

Comment: How do you start the servers in the first place, and how do they restart?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script to start multiple servers in a tmux session with different windows.

```
#!/bin/bash
SESSION='minecraft_servers'

tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION

# Setup a window for server 1
tmux rename-window 'server1'
tmux send-keys "cd /server1_dir; java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar" C-m

# Setup a window for server 2
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:1 -n 'server2' 
tmux send-keys "cd /server2_dir; java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar" C-m

# Setup a window for server 3
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:2 -n 'server3' 
tmux send-keys "cd /server3_dir; java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar" C-m

...(start more servers here the same as the two above)

# Set default window to first window
tmux select-window -t $SESSION:0
```

After this script runs you just use the tmux attach command to open the sessions like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the folowing script:

```bash
sleep 1
tmux send-keys -t $TMUX_PANE "java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar" C-m
```

`send-keys` command sends keys to an existing pane.

`-t` option specifys target pane in the format `<session>:<window>.<pane>` or using pane ID. You can get current pane ID from TMUX_PANE environment variable.

Write your command after this option. Use quotes: spaces must be sent too. Add `C-m` key after your command. It means Ctrl+m. Same as if you type "Enter"

This script sends your command to your pane. This pane must exists and it must be terminal that can run your command. So you should prepare your pane before.

If `/restart` command of spigot server called then server stops and execute your script **at the end of stopping**. So we need add `sleep` command to wait after sever stopped. Otherwise, your command will be executed in the server console (not in terminal).